# Понятен ли код функции без комментариев?

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

Написал функцию, и после того как написал ее, мне она показалась слишком запутанной *(сам я ее понимаю)*, интересно было бы узнать можно ли без контекста и комментариев понять ее смысл, т.к. этот код пойдет на гитлаб:

```cpp
struct kodik_material_title_t {
    char *psz_unique;
    char *psz_original;
    char *psz_other;
};

int
libkodik_material_title_from_json(json_object const *p_json, struct kodik_material_title_t **pp_object) {
    json_object *p_unique, *p_original, *p_other;
    json_bool b_json;
    int i_result = -11; /* Bad json object */
    if (0 != (b_json = json_object_object_get_ex(p_json, "title", &p_unique))) {
        if (0 != (b_json = json_object_object_get_ex(p_json, "title_orig", &p_original))) {
            if (0 == (i_result = libkodik_material_title_new(pp_object))) {
                size_t i_unique = 0, i_original = 0, i_other = 0;
                i_unique = json_object_get_string_len(p_unique);
                i_original = json_object_get_string_len(p_original);
                if (0 != (b_json = json_object_object_get_ex(p_json, "other_title", &p_other))) {
                    i_other = json_object_get_string_len(p_other);
                }
                if ( (NULL != ((*pp_object)->psz_unique     = calloc(i_unique   + 1, sizeof(char)))) &&
                      NULL != ((*pp_object)->psz_original   = calloc(i_original + 1, sizeof(char))) ||
                     (NULL != (1 != b_json/* no field other_title ??? cmp NULL & NULL else cmp with result of calloc */
                                ? NULL
                                : ((*pp_object)->psz_other = calloc(i_other    + 1, sizeof(char)))))) {
                    (void) strncpy((*pp_object)->psz_unique, json_object_get_string(p_unique), i_unique);
                    (void) strncpy((*pp_object)->psz_original, json_object_get_string(p_original), i_original);
                    if (0 != b_json) {
                        (void) strncpy((*pp_object)->psz_other, json_object_get_string(p_other), i_other);
                    }
                } else {
                    i_result = -10;
                    libkodik_material_title_free(pp_object);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return i_result;
}
```

Comment: Понять-то можно всегда, вопрос в том, сколько на это уйдет времени и душевных страданий.

Comment: Код не читается как минимум из-за длинных идентификаторов, полного отсутствия пустого вертикального пространства и какого-то адски-длинного условия в `if`, где еще и память выделяется. Спасибо, пострадал немного :) P. S. Очевидно, что в суть не вникал.

Comment: бессмысленные операции в коде заставляют задуматься. оптимизатор компилятора сразу же их вычеркнет. Но скорее всего алгоритм неправильный. Например, зачем переменной `b_json` присваивать значение, если потом это не используется? Баг скорее всего подумает программист. Оптимизировать можно подумает компилятор. Переменной `->psz_other` задаётся значение при каком-то условии, а потом *может быть* ей присвоится другое *или измениться*? *(Я думаю здесь будет UB).* Чтобы не было таких сложностей напишите всё в разных функциях.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, хм, и правда, пару присваиваний выкинул, но значение используется для того что бы определить нужно ли выделение памяти под данное поле, и нужно ли копировать данные, но UB там точно не будет, т.к. значение только в данном месте может быть присвоено, реализация структуры скрыта.

Comment: В большом ифе где `&& ||` без скобок вы понимаете, то в `->psz_other` может быть не выделено памяти вообще? Там ленивые вычисления, если вы не знали.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JztA.jpg но и помимо этого код - просто жесть... А в качестве комментария должна быть, как минимум, указана опциональность аргументов, параметры владения, и значения волшебных чисел, возвращаемых в качестве результата.

Comment: Понимает ли автор функцию нужно проверять не сразу после написания, а хотя бы через месяц-два.

Comment: @eanmos Чем вам длина идентификаторов не понравилась? Вот Макконнелл приводит данные, что оптимальная длина для имени переменной - 9..15 символов, для методов - длиннее. А в С вообще сложно давать функциям короткие имена из-за необходимости поддерживать их глобальную уникальность.

Comment: суффикс `_t` обычно дается алиасам типов, т.е. можно было бы ожидать, что `kodik_material_title_t` не потребует указывать struct

Comment: @user7860670, дело скорее не в самих длинных идентификаторах, а в том, что здесь они образуют очень длинные строки, а глазу чисто физиологически неудобно перепрыгивать с конца одной длинной строки на начало следующей. Тем более, когда строки слеплены в одну большую кашу. Оптимальная длина строки, согласно Брингхерсту — 66 символов :) Ну, и мне кажется очевидным, что при *прочих равных*, чем короче, тем лучше.

Comment: @eanmos, Ну даже не знаю про длину строк, на моем мониторе еще [полно места](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUmbu.png), шрифт 125% ну и [окно на весь экран](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Qj6.png)

Comment: Понятно, что мониторы сейчас широкие и места много, но дело не в этом. Вот, взгляните на [скриншот](https://imgur.com/S5ai82C) — ваш код справа, код слева из [DOOM-IOS2](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-IOS2/blob/master/common/libtess/mesh.c) (`libtess` — эталонный C код как минимум по стилю, ИМХО). Видите общую динамику двух листингов? Ваш код „широкий“, сливается в одну большую массу, «не дышит». Код справа — „узкий“, с короткими строками, большим вертикальным пространством и короткими идентификаторами.

Comment: в коде `1 != b_json/* no field other_title ??? cmp NULL & NULL else cmp with result of calloc */ ? NULL`  приоритет выше у `1 != b_json`. То есть `(1 != b_json)?NULL`. То есть `NULL` никогда не будет. ужас...

Comment: @mik.ov, и еще — `sizeof(char)` всегда равен 1. Поэтому, можно писать просто `1`.